# Reading xml file using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I am using the below code to read one xml file which is located locally. But its not displaying the object of xmldoc. My code is

```
function loadXMLDoc(XMLname)
{
  var xmlDoc;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
    xmlDoc=new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlDoc.open("GET",XMLname,false);
     xmlDoc.send("");
     return xmlDoc.responseXML;
   }

   else if (ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM"))
   {
   xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async=false;
   xmlDoc.load(XMLname);
   return xmlDoc;
   }
   alert("Error loading document!");
   return null;
   }



   function f1()
   {
   var xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc(“test.xml”)
   var M = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(“article”);
   alert(M);
     }
```

Its not displaying the alert if i call the function f1.Thanks in advance

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous. Wait for xmlDoc to load, then parse its response data.

Comment: sorry i can't get u.I have to download anyother file for this?. whats mean by waiting for xmlDoc to load. Pls help

Comment: This is among the basics of AJAX. I would recommend you find an AJAX tutorial; it will explain better than I can.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Better use Jquery function. Its working fine for me.

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "read2.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('site').each(function(){

            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var title = $(this).find('title').text();
            var url = $(this).find('url').text();
            $(this).find('desc').each(function()
            {
                var brief = $(this).find('brief').text();
                var long = $(this).find('long').text();
                alert("my "+brief );
                alert("my "+long );

            });
        });
    }
});
});
```

And the XML file format will be

my title1
url1

brf 1
long 1

brf 2
long 2