# how to retrieve specific element from xml file and return its node using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

how to retrieve data from xml in javascript.

data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Lexical-Entry>
    <Synset>
        <Word val="aare"/>
        <SynsetRelation>
            <Relation att="iof" hypernym="thing" val="river"/>
        </SynsetRelation>
        <ID WordnetId="09186064" uw_id="1"/>
    </Synset>
    <Synset>
        <Word val="aarhus"/>
        <SynsetRelation>
            <Relation att="iof" hypernym="thing" val="city"/>
            <Relation att="equ" val="arhus"/>
        </SynsetRelation>
        <ID WordnetId="08762104" uw_id="2"/>
    </Synset>
    <Synset>
        <Word val="aaron"/>
        <SynsetRelation>
            <Relation att="icl" hypernym="abstract_thing" val="name"/>
            <Relation att="com" val="male"/>
            <Relation att="nam" val="person"/>
        </SynsetRelation>
        <ID WordnetId="0" uw_id="3"/>
    </Synset>
</Lexical-Entry>
```

test.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
                <h1>Search Word</h1>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" name="SearchValue" placeholder="Enter a word" />
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit"  value="Search"/>
            </div>

</body>
</html>
```

when user enters a word to search for ex:aaron it should retrieve values of aaron synset. and when user enters word it should search that word in data.xml and then retrieves values of aaron synset.

Comment: Have you checked out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083341/is-there-a-way-to-getelement-xml-by-attribute)?
It might answer your question.

Comment: @Asagnome yes i checked it out but it was not that much that i required.
i require the complete node when user searches a word aaron and that node should be stored so that i can access its child values.

Answer (score 0):

Not fully understood your question, but this code extracts `Synset` element from xml string where `Name` node value is `aaron`.

It should give you idea how to fetch what you need. If no, when post more code about how and what you are trying to achieve.

```
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><Lexical-Entry><Synset><Word val="aare"/><SynsetRelation><Relation att="iof" hypernym="thing" val="river"/></SynsetRelation><ID WordnetId="09186064" uw_id="1"/></Synset><Synset><Word val="aarhus"/><SynsetRelation><Relation att="iof" hypernym="thing" val="city"/><Relation att="equ" val="arhus"/></SynsetRelation><ID WordnetId="08762104" uw_id="2"/></Synset><Synset><Word val="aaron"/><SynsetRelation><Relation att="icl" hypernym="abstract_thing" val="name"/><Relation att="com" val="male"/><Relation att="nam" val="person"/></SynsetRelation><ID WordnetId="0" uw_id="3"/></Synset></Lexical-Entry>'

var parsedXml = (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml')
var valueToLookFor = 'aaron';
var node = parsedXml.querySelector('Word[val="' + valueToLookFor +'"]').parentNode
```

Comment: instead of using xml content within variable how to extract it from xml file .?

Comment: just use `XMLHttpRequest` or `$.ajax` as in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12085181/reading-xml-file-using-javascript

Comment: can you help me out how to use d3.js with it for loading external xml file ?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with d3.js, but you can get file from server to browser using `$.ajax` like I mentioned in previous comment.

Comment: can you provide me a snippet for it.? i tried using ajax i m not able to get it.

Comment: $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "read2.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('site').each(function(){
               //this is the file content. Do what you need to do
        });
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

If you reuse the code of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083341/is-there-a-way-to-getelement-xml-by-attribute), you can achieve it.

You get the parent node of the `<Word val="aaron"/>`.

The code below is ugly since the original one was. So I recommand you to completely redo your own but you have the idea.

```js
Array.prototype.where = function(matcher) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (matcher(this[i])) {
            result.push(this[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
};

function getElementsByAttribute(tag, attr, attrValue) {
    //Get elements and convert to array
    var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName(tag), 0);
    
    //Matches an element by its attribute and attribute value
    var matcher = function(el) {
        return el.getAttribute(attr) == attrValue;
    };

    return elems.where(matcher);
}

var elems = getElementsByAttribute('Word', 'val', 'aaron');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  console.log(elems[i].parentNode);
  // !!! HERE IS YOUR XML NODE -> elems[i] !!!
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Lexical-Entry>
    <Synset>
        <Word val="aare"/>
        <SynsetRelation>
            <Relation att="iof" hypernym="thing" val="river"/>
        </SynsetRelation>
        <ID WordnetId="09186064" uw_id="1"/>
    </Synset>
    <Synset>
        <Word val="aarhus"/>
        <SynsetRelation>
            <Relation att="iof" hypernym="thing" val="city"/>
            <Relation att="equ" val="arhus"/>
        </SynsetRelation>
        <ID WordnetId="08762104" uw_id="2"/>
    </Synset>
    <Synset>
        <Word val="aaron"/>
        <SynsetRelation>
            <Relation att="icl" hypernym="abstract_thing" val="name"/>
            <Relation att="com" val="male"/>
            <Relation att="nam" val="person"/>
        </SynsetRelation>
        <ID WordnetId="0" uw_id="3"/>
    </Synset>
</Lexical-Entry>
```

Comment: how can i fetch data from external xml file and then how can i access

Comment: So like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684145/how-to-retrieve-xml-data-from-javascript ?

It uses **XHR**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest .

The doc is well done, with examples and you don't have to use jQuery (and so ajax).